# How to detect when tap on google map iOS Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, gesture, tap

I want to check and detect when tap on map marker or anything. Do any delegates exist for this case with google maps in iOS Swift 4?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
 func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didTapAt coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
 //Write your code here...
 }
```

if the delegate function is not called then set the mapview delegate in `viewDidAppear()` method or in `LocationManager` `didUpdateLocations()` method.